# Angular 6 multiples app deployed in firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, multiple-projects

I have a angular 6 app with multiple projects, i configure my rewrite rules to the following:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/ticket/**",
    "destination": "/ticket-app/index.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/client/**",
    "destination": "/client-app/index.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/admin/**",
    "destination": "/admin-app/index.html"
  }
],
```

The application is deployed without error, but when go to the urls, the applications not working correctly, the .js are no load for the browser. When you viisit the url of the .js is get only the .html page.I can see the following error in the developer console:

[image: Chrome console]
[image: Chrome console]

All get request to .js files and .css files always return index.html page, i try other rewrite formats like this:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/ticket/**",
    "destination": "/ticket-app/**"
  },
  {
    "source": "/client/**",
    "destination": "/client-app/"
  },
  {
    "source": "/admin/**",
    "destination": "/admin-app/*"
  }
],
```

But no working. I build the app with the command:

```
ng build ticket-app --prod --base-href '/ticket/'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `deployUrl`. There are 2 options

1) add `--deploy-url` param when building the application

```
ng build ticket-app --prod --base-href '/ticket/'
```

2) Add configuration in `angular.json` for each application

```
"build": {
          "options": {
            ...
            "baseHref": "/ticket/",
            "deployUrl": "/ticket/"
          },
 ...
}
```